# How do I display all posts based on category?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

For example i will have 4 categories. For each category i will show 5 recent post. I will have category such as breakfast, dessert, lunch and savory food. There will be a "see all" link for each category, so the user can see all the breakfast category post. On the main page i will list 5 recent post and when the users click the "see all" link it will link them to the whole breakfast category. I want all breakfast in that category if the they click "see all". The same for other categories. 
Currently my code looks like this, but i'm stuck with the "see all" link. I don't know how to link it to main category.

```html
<?php 

get_header();

?> 

<!-- recipe -->
<section class="recipe-wrap">

 <?php
 /*
  * Loop through Categories and Display Posts within
  */
 $post_type = 'recipe';
 $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
  
 // Get all the taxonomies for this post type
 $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
  
 foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
  
     // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
     $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
  
     foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

 <div class="recipe-category owl-carousel-slide">
  <div class="row">

   <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?><a href="#">see all</a></h2>
         
         <div class="recipe-category-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">

          <?php
          $args = array(
                  'post_type' => $post_type,
                  'posts_per_page' => 10,  //show all posts
                  'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                          'field' => 'slug',
                          'terms' => $term->slug,
                      )
                  )
   
              );
          $posts = new WP_Query($args);
   
          if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

             <div class="item recipe-box">

              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo(types_render_field('artwork', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">
                  <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                 </a>
             </div> 

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
           </div>
          
           </section>
    
       <?php endforeach;
    
   endforeach; ?>

         </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /recipe -->

<?php 

get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please help answerers and future readers by posting a minimal, complete and verifiable example instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

   // Get term link by using get_term_link()

   $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

   echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';

}
```

Comment: right now it showing 2 terms name (which I use "see all"). I want to show 1 term name (see all) for each category. How do I do thaT?

Comment: I need include the code i provide right? can u show me too? including my code plus your code please? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mini_stream">
    <ul>
<? $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'category_name'=>'Product',
);

$loop = new wp_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'category-thumb');
    the_title( '<h6>', '</h6>' );
    echo '</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

=> Using this method may you get all post